# Why Unity provide "enabling toggle" on script when it goes in Editor folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

I have a monobehaviour class that I use in UnityEditor. It looks like this:
[image]

When I put it into the Editor folder, the inspector changes into this:
[image]

Why this happening and what does it mean ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enabling checkbox for a mono behaviour script means that it contains 'Start' or 'Update' methods. You can prevent unity from calling these methods by disabling the checkbox. If your script does not contain either of these methods then the checkbox disappears.

However for an editor script it is somehow different. Editor classes don't work with 'Start' and 'Update' so the checkbox appears there.

Comment: Thank you! Got it!

Comment: @VladislavHromyh Hi, you can absolutely accept answer if it solved your problem.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for how to do that.